Integrating MLflow with GitLab: Getting 404 Project Not Found Error
I am working on a project that involves using MLflow and GitLab integration. I have set up a Jupyter notebook where I aim to integrate data from MLflow into GitLab. Following the instructions provided here (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/ml/experiment_tracking/mlflow_client.html), I have generated a personal access token and specified the URI for my project as follows:
os.environ["MLFLOW_TRACKING_TOKEN"] = "token"
os.environ["MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI"] = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v4/projects/ID_project/ml/mlflow"

Prior to running this code, I have started the MLflow server using mlflow server --host 127.0.0.1 --port 5000. However, when I run the code, I encounter a common issue: 404 Project Not Found. I have followed the instructions precisely, and it seems like a straightforward setup, but I cannot seem to resolve this error.
According to my link, where I open http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v4/projects/ID_project/ml/mlflow it gives the following error
RestException: INTERNAL_ERROR: Response: {'error': '404 Not Found'}

The MLFlow project itself on port 5000 is launched successfully with all experiments.
I have searched extensively for solutions and found a discussion related to this issue here https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/29022. However, the solutions provided there do not seem to apply to my situation.
I need help understanding why the model registry functionality is unavailable and how to connect MLflow to GitLab correctly. How can I resolve the 404 Not Found error and use the GitLab model registry with MLflow?
If anyone has encountered and resolved this issue before or has any insights into what might be causing it, I would greatly appreciate your help. Thank you in advance!"
Logging MLflow experiments to GitLab did not work due to the 404 Not Found error.
Connecting to the MLflow model registry resulted in UnsupportedModelRegistryStoreURIException.

What kind of token are you using? My tests suggest that a project access token is generating a 404 error, while a personal access token seems to work.
